# jquery jqgrid not loading up

Tags: jquery, asp.net, jqgrid

So all the javascript loads fine except for the jqGrid. It's giving me this error:

> jQuery("#resultsGrid").jqGrid is not a function

Which I'm assuming means it can't find the .js source. However, it is in my main Js folder along with all the other goodies, and everything else seems to work fine. Plus, none of the other javascript needs to reference the grid stuff as a source, so if I reference it in the script tag, it will break everything else right?

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {

        $("#prepaymentTable").bubble({ width: 400, title: 'Prepayment' });
        $("#exposureTable").bubble({ width: 400, title: 'Exposure' });

        $('#calculateButton').live('click', function () {
            alert('Calculating Prepayment Analysis...');
        });

        $('#exposureButton').live('click', function () {
            alert('Calculating Exposure Analysis...');
        });

        jQuery("#resultsGrid").jqGrid({
            datatype: "local",
            height: 250,
            colNames: ['Inv No', 'Date', 'Client', 'Amount', 'Tax', 'Total', 'Notes'],
            colModel: [
                { name: 'id', index: 'id', width: 60, sorttype: "int" },
                { name: 'invdate', index: 'invdate', width: 90, sorttype: "date" },
                { name: 'name', index: 'name', width: 100 },
                { name: 'amount', index: 'amount', width: 80, align: "right", sorttype: "float" },
                { name: 'tax', index: 'tax', width: 80, align: "right", sorttype: "float" },
                { name: 'total', index: 'total', width: 80, align: "right", sorttype: "float" },
                { name: 'note', index: 'note', width: 150, sortable: false }
            ], multiselect: true,
            caption: "Manipulating Array Data"
        });
        var mydata = [
            { id: "1", invdate: "2007-10-01", name: "test", note: "note", amount: "200.00", tax: "10.00", total: "210.00" },
            { id: "2", invdate: "2007-10-02", name: "test2", note: "note2", amount: "300.00", tax: "20.00", total: "320.00" },
            { id: "3", invdate: "2007-09-01", name: "test3", note: "note3", amount: "400.00", tax: "30.00", total: "430.00" },
            { id: "4", invdate: "2007-10-04", name: "test", note: "note", amount: "200.00", tax: "10.00", total: "210.00" },
            { id: "5", invdate: "2007-10-05", name: "test2", note: "note2", amount: "300.00", tax: "20.00", total: "320.00" },
            { id: "6", invdate: "2007-09-06", name: "test3", note: "note3", amount: "400.00", tax: "30.00", total: "430.00" },
            { id: "7", invdate: "2007-10-04", name: "test", note: "note", amount: "200.00", tax: "10.00", total: "210.00" },
            { id: "8", invdate: "2007-10-03", name: "test2", note: "note2", amount: "300.00", tax: "20.00", total: "320.00" },
            { id: "9", invdate: "2007-09-01", name: "test3", note: "note3", amount: "400.00", tax: "30.00", total: "430.00" }
            ];
        for (var i = 0; i <= mydata.length; i++)
            jQuery("#resultsGrid").jqGrid('addRowData', i + 1, mydata[i]); 

        }); 
    </script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should verify that you loaded the jqGrid files in the correct order (see [documentation](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki%3afirst_grid#html_file)). **Typical error is including `"i18n/grid.locale-en.js"` after the `"jquery.jqGrid.min.js"`**. If it not help you you should append your question with the information about loading of JavaScript files and CSS files which you use.